# Python if statement without == operator

Tags: python, if-statement, modulo

Can someone explain to me how this function works? I don't get how the for loop keeps going while there is `return False` after the if statement, which is also unclear to me.

```
def IsPrime(n):
    for x in range(2, int(n/2+1)):
        if not n % x:
            return False;
    return True
```

I don't understand what is happening in line 3 of this code.

Comment: It checks the *truthiness* of the expression.

Comment: [Truth Value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth)

Comment: n % x returns a number. Try `bool(6)` and `bool(0)` in the Python shell

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** the `if` fires when `n` is *dividable* by `x`.

**Background**:

If you write something with:

```
if <expr>:
    pass
```

The `not` keyword also evaluates the *truthiness*, and in case the truthiness is `True` of the expression, then `not expression` is `False` and vice versa.

Python checks the [***truthiness***](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs258/truthiness-in-python) of the `<expr>`. The truthiness is a boolean value that is associated with objects.

`True` and `False` have as truthiness respectively `True` and `False`, and `None` has truthiness `False` (so we can check `if someobject` usually to do an implicit `None` check).

Collections like `list`s, `set`s, `dict`s, `tuple`s, etc. usually have truthiness `True` if and *only* if these collections contain at *least* one element. So empty collections have truthiness `False`. What these collections contain is of no importance for the truthiness of the collection itself.

Then there are also numerical types. Usually a number has truthiness `False` if and only if it is equal to zero, so negative and strictly positive numbers have truthiness `True`.

Generic objects have by default truthiness `True`, but you can override the `__bool__` magic function to return a different truthiness, or if you override `__len__` (and not `__bool__`), it will check if `__len__` is greater than zero.

So if `n` and `x` are integers, then we calculate `n % x`, this thus performs a *modulo* check, and `n % x` is zero if and only if `n` is dividable by `x`.

Now the `not` operator will thus evaluate the truthiness. In case `n` is dividable by `x`, then `not n % x` is `True`, otherwise `not n % x` is `False`.

So the `if` is fired if `n` is dividable by `x`. The prime test thus checks if `n` is dividable by all numbers between `2` and `n/2+1`, and if not, it returns `True`, from the moment one is dividable, it returns `False`.

We can however speed up the calculations by iterating up to the *square root* of `n`, and make hops of two:

```
from math import sqrt

def IsPrime(n):
    if not n % 2:
        return False
    for x in range(3, int(sqrt(n)), 2):
        if not n % x:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

What follows after `if`, will be casted to type `bool`, i.e. even though you put an integer in, python will have to cast it to `bool`, because `if` can only branch on the boolean values `True` or `False`.
Now python evaluates all numbers except 0 to `True` in the `bool(number)` function. So basically `if not n%x` is the same thing as `if not ((n%x) != 0)`.

Example `x=2`: code inside the loop will be executed for even values of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

In line 3, you divide `n` by integers between `2 to n/2`,now lets look at `if not n%x:`,here if x divides n completely then `n%x` returns `0` which is interpreted as `False`.Now `not` of `False` is `True` therefore condition evaluates to True and your `IsPrime(n)` function returns `False`.So,any number `n` which has a factor between `2` and `n-1` or more precisely between `2 and n/2` is Not a Prime Number,So your function returned false else your function will evaluate to `True`.